# Run BlackBerry PhoneGap application in background

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a BlackBerry application in PhoneGap, Cordova. I need to run the application in the background to send the SMS at an interval of 15 minutes.

Is this possible in a PhoneGap project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a project for BBOS based devices (6.0, 7.0) then this can be done by adding an entry to your config.xml - http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/rim_background_element_1265316_11.html.

If you want the app to remain running in the background when the user closes the app, you will need to trap the back event.